# How to remove stop words in OSX terminal?

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, nlp

For now, I have a txt file made by 6 Shakespeare books and I am going to remove stopwords based on a [prepared stop word list](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/igorbrigadir/stopwords/master/en/99webtools.txt).

Firstly, I create an empty txt file and duplicate the original txt file's content in lowercase to the new file(because the stop word list are made by lowercase words).

```
$cat new_txt.txt | tr [A-Z] [a-z] > new_txt_lowercase.txt
```

Then, I use the code below to erase stop words in stop word list:

```
$ grep -wvf 99webtools.txt new_txt_lowercase.txt>new_txt_no_stopwords.txt

$ grep -v -f 99webtools.txt new_txt_lowercase.txt>new_txt_no_stopwords.txt
```

But neither of them works.

Any ideas? is there anything wrong with my code?

Comment: you need to put each word on its own line if you want to use `grep -v`.

Comment: @Barmar should I remove -v or use -wf instead of -wvf?

Comment: You should put each word on its own line, then use `grep -xvf`

Comment: The point is that `grep -v` filters out whole lines, not just the part of the line that matches. You can use `grep -o` to show just the part that matches, but I don't think there's anything opposite to that.

Comment: If one of the above comments brings a solution, don't forget you can post that as an answer to your own questions. Then it is here for the next person.